# Asysctask and home button

Tags: android, android-asynctask

Im using some methods in background with async task.
When the processor is running and I press the "home button"
my application close. It does not crash, it simple close.
The async task finishes its functions, but there is no feed back
to the user is has finished ok or not, the alert dialog is not 
show.

Answer (score 1):

If your app is not running, there is no way to display anything on the UI thread.

Use a Notification if you want to display a message to the user, when your application is not in context.  It is pretty easy to issue a simple push notification (and doesn't even require a special permission).

You should not use a "Toast" message".  It will still require context (which you won't have since your app is not running).  Also a toast can be confusing to the user if they are not aware where it is coming from (random messages showing up on the screen are confusing).

It doesn't change my answer on how to send this message, but be aware that when you "press the home button", your app does NOT close.  It is still running, just off the UI thread.  You can still use resources in the app.  Without special coding, you can not be sure how long it will remain running, so you should still send the message using a notification.

Comment: My app close in this process. I don't know why. It closes, from lack of memory or anithing else.

Comment: Look in Logcat.  There will be a stacktrace showing what your issue is.  You can use the lifecycle methods of AsyncTask to monitor outcomes of the task too.